# Venn diagram with rectangles for $n > 3$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinatorial-geometry, rectangles

Is it possible to draw a Venn diagram with rectangles for $n > 3$? If yes, is it possible for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$? If no, up to which $n$ is it possible?

Furthermore, the rectangles should have the following properties

- same width and height
- axis-aligned (not rotated)

Comment: By same size, do you mean same area, or same side lengths?

Comment: @­Arthur Thank's for that hint, I've updated my question. I meant the same width and height.

Comment: Can they be rotated, then? Also, since I had already done it before noticing the "same size" requirement, [here](https://i.imgur.com/4mncc9c.png) is a Venn diagram with four different-sized rectangles.

Comment: Oh, it seems I need to work on my questioning. The rectangles should be axis-aligned. Okay, that gives me a first impression. It seems to be possible for $n=4$.

Comment: can they be rotated? still axis aligned but rotated by $\pi/2$

Comment: No, they can't be rotated...

Comment: I saw your edit :) thx

Comment: ***REALLY*** not a set theory problem.

Comment: It’s probably better to ask a new question instead of adding the extras - your original question is interesting and has a good answer. You get more rep that way too.

Comment: I'll do that. Thank's :)

Comment: @MaxWell - I do not see an $n=4$ solution with your "same width and height" and "not rotated" requirements (you may as well say axis-aligned squares)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Solving the given problem I tried different approaches, obtaining better and better bounds. Also the last bound is the best, I leave the other too, because they can help to solve similar problems.

**Bound 4.** I claim that $n\le 3$. Indeed, assume to the contrary, there exists a family $\mathcal R$ of $4$ (congruent) rectangles representing  Venn diagram. 
Define two orders $\le_x$ and $\le_y$ on $\mathcal R$. Namely, for rectangles $R,R’\in\mathcal R$ put $R\le_t R’$ if $t$-coordinate of the left side of the rectangle $R$ in not bigger that $t$-coordinate of the left side of the rectangle $R’$. Let $R_1\le_x R_2\le_x  R_3\le_x R_4$ be the enumeration of the family $\mathcal R$.

Assume first that $R_1$ or $R_4$ is a minimal or a maximal element of $(\mathcal R,\le_y)$. Applying, if needed, to the plane transformations $x\mapsto -x$ and $y\mapsto -y$, without loss of generality we may suppose that  $R_1$ is a minimal element of $(\mathcal R,\le_y)$. If $R_2\le_y R_4$ then $R_1\cap R_4\subset R_2$,
contradicting the property of Venn diagram. If $R_3\le_y R_4$ then $R_1\cap R_4\subset R_3$, contradicting the property of Venn diagram. Thus $R_4\le_y R_2$ and $R_4\le_y R_3$. Now if  $R_2\le_y R_3$ then $R_1\cap R_3\subset R_2$, contradicting the property of Venn diagram and if  $R_3\le_y R_2$ then $R_2\cap R_4\subset R_3$, contradicting the property of Venn diagram.

Thus in the order $\le_y$ the elements $R_1$ and $R_4$ are placed between elements $R_2$ and $R_3$. But then $R_1\cap R_4\subset R_2\cup R_3$, contradicting the property of Venn diagram. Indeed, assume to contrary that there is an (interior) point $R_1\cap R_4\setminus (R_2\cup R_3)$. Let $\ell$ be a horizontal straight line going through the point $x$. It is easy to see that if $\ell$ intersects any of rectangles $R_2$ or $R_3$ then it contradicts the choice of $R_1$ or $R_4$ as a leftmost or a rightmost rectangle. Since $R_2$ and $R_3$ intersects, both $R_2$ and $R_3$ lie above $\ell$ or both $R_2$ and $R_3$ lie below $\ell$, a contradiction with that $R_2$ and $R_3$ are topmost and bottommost rectangles.

[image]

**Bound 3.** I claim that $n\le 4$. Indeed, assume to the contrary, there exists a family $\mathcal R$ of $n\ge 5$ (congruent) rectangles representing  Venn diagram. Define two orders $\le_x$ and $\le_y$ on $\mathcal R$. Namely, for rectangles $R,R’\in\mathcal R$ put $R\le_t R’$ if $t$-coordinate of the left side of the rectangle $R$ in not bigger that $t$-coordinate of the left side of the rectangle $R’$. By [Erdős–Szekeres theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Szekeres_theorem) there exist distinct rectangles $R,R’,R’’\in\mathcal R$ such that $R\le_x R’\le_x R’’$ and either $R\le_y R’\le_y R’’$ or $R’’\le_y R’\le_y R$. Anyway, $R\cap R’’\subset R’$, contradicting the property of Venn diagram.

**Bound 2.** A more tight upper bound for $n$ can be obtained as follows. Given a partition of the plane into domains by rectangles, consider corners of these domains as vertices of a graph $G$ and the segments of sides of rectangles connecting some of the corners as vertices of the graph. Then each of rectangles of the family contributes at most $4$ its corners to the total number $c$ of the corners, and each two different rectangles of the family additionally contribute to this number at most $4$ in the general case and at most $2$ in your case. Thus $c\le 4n+2n(n-1)=2n^2+2n$ in the general case and $c\le 4n+n(n-1)=n^2+3n$ vertices in your case.

Now double count a number $N$ of pairs $(e, f)$ where $e$ is a edge of the graph $G$ incident to its face $f$. Since, by the construction, each face $f$ of the graph $G$ 
has degree at least $4$, it contributes at least $4$ to the sum for $N$, implying $N\ge 4r$, where $r$ is the number of faces of the graph $G$, equal to the number of domains in which the rectangles partition the plane. On the other hand, each edge $e$ of $G$ is incident to exactly $2$ faces (we also count the outer face, if needed), so it contributes exactly $2$ to the sum for $N$, implying $N=2m$, where $m$ is the number of edges of the graph $G$.  Thus $2m=N\ge 4r$.

Combining the obtained inequality with Euler’s formula $c-m+r=2$, we obtain $r=2+m-c\le m/2$, or $m+4\le 2c$. Then $r=2+m-c\le 2c-2-c=c-2$, which is at most 
$2n^2+2n-2$ in the general case and at most $n^2+3n-2$ in your case. 
The inequality $r\ge 2^n$ implies $n\le 6$ in the general case and $n\le 5$ in your case.

**Bound 1.** Even in a general case, when we do not require that the rectangles has the same width and height, the family consisting of $n$ rectangles span by their sizes at most $2n$ lines parallel to each of the coordinate axis. So they can partition the plane into at most $(2n+1)^2$ domains,  whereas Venn’s diagram has $2^n$ domains. So $(2n+1)^2\ge 2^n$, which yields $n\le 8$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your great answer and your incredible efforts. It's perfect.

Answer (score 6):

Suppose you have a Venn diagram with $n$ axis-aligned rectangles of the same width and height. By a scaling of the axes, we may assume the rectangles are all squares. Let's show that it's not possible to have a Venn diagram with $n$ axis-aligned squares for $n\ge4$, *even if the squares are allowed to be of different sizes*.

Suppose there were such a Venn diagram. By shrinking squares as necessary, we can assume the diagram is simple -- that is, each point of intersection of the perimeters of the squares is an intersection of just two squares. In that case, each pair of squares intersects exactly twice, for a total of $2{n\choose2}=n(n-1)$ vertices for the diagram, which implies a total of $2n(n-1)$ (topological) edges. From Euler's formula, $V-E+F=2$, we have

$$F=2+n(n-1)$$

and it's elementary to show that $2^n\gt2+n(n-1)$ for $n\ge4$.

Remark: Because each region in a Venn diagram is an intersection of *interiors*, the shrinking step(s) can clearly be engineered to leave an open set for each of the $2^n$ intersections, but it's conceivable you could wind up with *duplicates* of some of the intersections --i.e., the diagram may no longer be a Venn diagram.  However, that doesn't matter for the argument here, since it simply says $F\ge2^n$.

Additional remark: The scaling was done for convenience, since it's clear that overlapping squares cannot intersect at more than two points (if the intersections are simple). This is also true for rectangles *with a common aspect ratio*. It's not true, of course, in general:  a tall skinny rectangle can intersect a short fat one at $4$ points as easily as $2$.

Comment: Very nice! It seems that your arguments work even for a family of pseudodiscs.

Comment: Yes, the claim for pseudo-discs follows from Theorem 7(?) of the  paper “[On k-intersecting curves and related problems](http://www2.math.technion.ac.il/~room/ps_files/kintersect_BHP.pdf)” by  Buzaglo, Holzman, and Pinchasi.

Comment: Thank's Barry for your nice answer.